# Sorting by multiple params in pyes and elasticsearch

Tags: python, sorting, elasticsearch

I can pass a single **sort** parameter to the search query in pyes like this:

```
s = MatchAllQuery()
conn.search(query=Search(s), indexes=["test"], sort='_score')
```

But I need to pass an extra parameter to sort the docs with the same score, like this:

```
{
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "extra_param": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this in pyes?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you'd like the results in the result set with the same score to be ordered by price, append price to the sort string:

```
s = MatchAllQuery()
conn.search(query=Search(s), indexes=["test"], sort='_score,price')
```

By default the sort order is ascending. To pass the sort order append **:asc** or **:desc** to the sort parameter

```
s = MatchAllQuery()
conn.search(query=Search(s), indexes=["test"], sort='_score,price:desc')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do more detailed sorting that what's available via `es.search`'s `sort` keyword, you can just pass the search dict into the `es.Search` constructor.

```
s = Search({'term': {'foo.monkey': 'george'}},
           sort=[{'_geo_distance': {'unit': 'mi',
                                    'order': 'desc',
                                    'monkey.location': '81,20'}}]) 
conn.search(s)
```