# Sort order in PyES

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

In PyES, i'm executing the following command:
`conn.search(query=_query, indices=self.index_name, doc_types=[self.document_type], sort="name")`

All well, I get a sort on name. However, I cannot find out how to change the order from ASC to DESC whilst sorting.

I've already tried things like:
`sort=[{'name':'desc}]` and `sort=[{'name':{'order':'desc'}]` as per the docs, but this yields no proper sort.

Any ideas on how to get the right sort order?

Comment: you know you can just reverse sort the list with python after it returned..? a little less efficient but gets the job done

Comment: sort = 'name:desc'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084536/sorting-by-multiple-params-in-pyes-and-elasticsearch